# cannot be cast to java.lang.String exception

Tags: java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RateTransmissionDetails")
public class RateTransmissionDetails implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String spaceNum;
    private Integer rateInCent;


    public RateTransmissionDetails() {
    }
    public RateTransmissionDetails(String spaceNum,Integer rateInCent) {

        this.spaceNum=spaceNum;
        this.rateInCent=rateInCent;
    } 


    @Column(name = "SpaceNum", nullable = false)
    public String getSpaceNum() {
        return this.spaceNum;
    }

    public void setSpaceNum(String spaceNum) {
        this.spaceNum = spaceNum;
    }

    @Column(name = "RateInCent", nullable = false)
    public Integer getRateInCent() {
        return this.rateInCent;
    }

    public void setRateInCent(Integer rateInCent) {
        this.rateInCent = rateInCent;
    }
```

and my service class is

```
Set<RateTransmissionDetails> rateTrmDtls = new HashSet<RateTransmissionDetails>();
rateTrmDtls.add((new RateTransmissionDetails("A",new Integer(20)));
```

I am getting the error

> 2012-11-02 16:44:02,796[http-6060-3] WARN  duncansolutions.databus.external.controller.rate.RateController - Error message to caller: com.duncansolutions.databus.external.bean.hibernate.rate.RateTransmissionDetails cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Can any body tell me how to go about it.

Comment: you should post all your service class code in order to figure out where the error occurs if that's all your stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<RateTransmissionDetails> rateTrmDtls = new HashSet<RateTransmissionDetails>(); 
rateTrmDtls.add(new RateTransmissionDetails("A",new Integer(20)));
```

There is nothing wrong here. The error probably occurs when you use that set `rateTrmDtls` to do something, and the code expects a set of `String`

Can you show the code where you use the set in `RateController`?